# How can I access local variables in my React function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined, before even the functions are even called. The error happens on the line slide[n].classlist.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    let currentSlide = 0;
    
    function showSlide(n) {
      slides[currentSlide].classList.remove('active-slide');
      slides[n].classList.add('active-slide');
      currentSlide = n;
      if (currentSlide === 0) {
        previousButton.style.display = 'none';
      }
      else {
        previousButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
      }
      if (currentSlide === slides.length - 1) {
        nextButton.style.display = 'none';
        //submitButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
      }
      else {
        nextButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
        //submitButton.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    function showNextSlide() {
      showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
    }

    function showPreviousSlide() {
      showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
    }
    
    const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
    const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
    previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide());
    nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide());
    console.log(slides);
    showSlide(0);
  }
```

Comment: Don't use the DOM API and conditionally add/remove styles based on local variables. Those variables should be in the `state` and changes to state will re-render your component.

Comment: Your error is on adjusting an undefined element from an array defined by `document.querySelectorAll(".slide");` Well, I don't see any elements with `className="slide"`.  In which case, the error message is correct.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post a minimal reproducible example (the complete page in this case, I guess), not just the function code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide());
nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide());
```

You are calling the functions instead of passing them as arguments. Because of that you call showSlides with n = -1 (The showPreviousSlide call comes first) and ofcourse the slides array doesn't have member -1 so it's undefined -> You do not check if the member exists before trying to use it's properties -> you get the error.

Also you really should'nt use this kind of vanilla js inside react it defeats the whole point of using react.

This is the correct code

```js
previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way in this case is to declare slides and currentSlide variables as "var" type instead of "let":

```
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    var currentSlide = 0;
```

Second option, with react you can use hooks to have global variables access along your code.

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';

    const showSlide = (n) => {
    
    //HOOK
    const [useSlide, setUseSlide] = useState();
    .
    .
    .
```